# Difference between Convert and Parse c#

Tags: c#, parsing, difference

I would like to know that what are differences between,

```
(int)Something;

int.Parse(Something);

Convert.ToInt32(Something);
```

I asked my friends and no body helped me about this subject.

Any help will be appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Because searching in Google is too mainstream..

Comment: Because SO is the developers Google..

Comment: Look at the source code of the framework...  Far more educational than asking your friends.

Comment: @Abbas, because it is the only site with answers?

Answer (score 9):

1) that is a cast

2) Parsing taking in a string and attempts to convert it to a  type.

3) Convert accepts an `object` as its paramerter

One major difference is that `Convert` does not throw a `ArgumentNullException` while `Parse` does. Your cast would also throw an exception if it null. You can get around that by using

```
(int?)Something;
```

Answer (score 4):

Your first case:

```
(int)Something;
```

is **Explicit cast**, so something would be a double/float etc. If it is a string you will get an error.

Second case:

```
int.Parse(Something)
```

[`int.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes sting as parameter so `Something` has to be a string type.

Third case:

```
Convert.ToInt32(Something);
```

[`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has many overloads which takes parameter of type `object`, `string`, `bool` etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, just read MSDN.

> Using the ToInt32(String) method is equivalent to passing value to the Int32.Parse(String) method.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToInt32(string)` is a static wrapper method for `Int32.Parse(string)`.

The Convert.ToInt32 is defined like (from ILSpy):

```
// System.Convert
/// <summary>Converts the specified string representation of a number to an equivalent 32-bit signed integer.</summary>
/// <returns>A 32-bit signed integer that is equivalent to the number in <paramref name="value" />, or 0 (zero) if <paramref name="value" /> is null.</returns>
/// <param name="value">A string that contains the number to convert. </param>
/// <exception cref="T:System.FormatException">
/// <paramref name="value" /> does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9). </exception>
/// <exception cref="T:System.OverflowException">
/// <paramref name="value" /> represents a number that is less than <see cref="F:System.Int32.MinValue" /> or greater than <see cref="F:System.Int32.MaxValue" />. </exception>
/// <filterpriority>1</filterpriority>
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static int ToInt32(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return int.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Comment: With a catch: `Convert.ToInt32` accepts null arguments, in which case it returns the default value (i.e., 0)